How to find min./max. possible alpha values for perceptually equal resulting color after blending 2 RGBA colors
I have a blending function, that correctly blends an sRGBA foreground color over another sRGBA background color by using premultiplied alpha blending.
blend_premultipy_alpha(srgba_color_foreground,srgba_color_background) => srgba_color_blend

In addition, I also have an additional function, that correctly returns a sRGBA color with a desired Alpha value, that looks perceptually equal as a given sRGBA foreground color on a sRGBA background color, that I can use in conjunction with the first function.
adjust_alpha(srgba_color_foreground, srgba_color_background, desired_alpha) => srgba_color_blend

This basically means, that the resulting color with the adjusted alpha value, when blended over the background color, will result in the same blended color as the original foreground color being blended over the same background color, which is why they also optically look the same, when then being drawn on top of the background color on the screen, if this is understandable.
The remaining issue I now have is, that depending on foreground and background color, only a limited range of desired alpha values can result in a new color with that alpha value, that looks perceptually the same as the original foreground color blended onto the background color. This is, because desired alpha values, that are too high or too low, just cannot return any color, that will blend over the background with the same result as the original foreground color being blended over the background color as the result will inevitable be too light or too dark up from a certain alpha value.
That's why I would like to create a function, that return the minimum and maximum possible alpha values, that can be asked for, that would still result in an perceptually equal blended color as the original foreground color on the background color.
I want to achieve that result by calculating the minimum and maximum values directly, not be iterating over all possible alpha values.
I already tried different approaches with ChatGPT, but couldn't get a working result yet. It constantly tells me, that it should be achievable by rearranging the blending formula (for each RGB channel c) for premultiplied alpha value:
c_blend = (c_fg * a_fg + c_bg * a_bg * (1 - a_fg)) / (a_fg + a_bg + (1 - a_fg))
Each time I get differing rearranged results like:
a_blend = (a_fg - (c_bg * a_bg * (1 - a_fg)) / c_fg
With the 3 results for the 3 channels (R, G, B) I should then use the max/min of these values to get the min/max possible alpha value, that can return a sRGBA color with that alpha value, that looks the same on the background color as the original foreground color.
But nothing seemed to work properly yet.
So I'd like to ask, if any expert could tell me, if it is actually possible to calculate the minimum and maximum possible desired alpha values, that could still lead to a suitable color with that alpha value, that would blend over an sRGBA background color with the same blending result as the original sRGBA foreground color with a different alpha value?
Thanks a lot for any help.

Also keep in mind that "perceptually equal" can vary by person doing the perceiving.  There are many kinds of color perception depending upon who you are and what type level of things like color-blindness you may or may not have.

Thanks, I know, what you mean, but that is not relevant here, I just wanted to describe the visual effect. As long as the effect is the same on the same device, as it should be the case, that's perfectly fine.
